# iOS 7 Grouped Table viewForHeaderInSection label offset in section 1

Tags: ios7, uitableview

I've implemented a custom viewForHeaderInSection as follows:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    CGRect sectionFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30.0f);
    float xInset = 16.0;
    RTUTableHeaderView
            *headerView =
            [[RTUTableHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:sectionFrame
                                   andBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]
                                            FontColor:[RTUColorHelper kSettingsTableCellFontColor]
                                          andFontSize:18.f
                                       withLabelFrame:CGRectMake(xInset, 10.f, sectionFrame.size.width - xInset, 20)];
    headerView.label.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    return headerView;

}
```

This pushes the labels down by 10pts so that they sit closer to the relevant section. In iOS6 it looks fine, but for iOS7 the label in the first section header is around 10pts further up than the others. If I take away the 10pt offset, the label for the first section sits at the top of the headerView whereas the others are vertically-centered in their header frames.

I could just frig the values for section 0 if it's a bug but would obviously rather not and wanted to check that I haven't forgotten something else or done something wrong.

The section headers are all the same height, heightForRowAtIndexPath returns 44.f

Comment: So what is the actual problem...?

Comment: hah, my bad... I had written 'In <iOS7 it looks fine', so everything from the '<' onwards got gobbled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the only way I managed to fix this problem was to add an offset to the first section header:

```
    if(section==0){
        CGRect labelFrame = headerView.label.frame;
        labelFrame.origin.y+=15.f;
        [headerView.label setFrame:labelFrame];
    }
```

If anyone has any better ideas I'd love to hear them!